# Let $A$ and $B$ be a non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ suppose that $a \leq b$ for every $a\in A$ and for every $b\in B$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be a non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ suppose  that $a \leq b$ for every $a\in A$ and for every $b\in B$ prove that there is a real number $c$ such that $c \geq a$  for every  $a \in A$ and $c\leq b$ for every $b \in B$

***My idea:***

given that $a \leq b$ by Archimedes property  in $\mathbb{R}$ , $\exists n \in N$ such that

$n(b-a) \geq 1 \Rightarrow nb\geq na+1$

Also $\exists$ a unique integer $m $ such that $m-1 \leq na<m $

$\therefore   nb \geq na+1 \geq n >na$

or $na \leq m \leq nb$ or $a \leq \frac{m}{n} \leq b $

Right?

Comment: You have just found a number between _some_ $a\in A$ and _some_ $b\in B$. There is no guarantee that $\frac mn\leq b'$ for all other $b'\in B$, and similarly for $A$. You need to find a single $c$ that _always works_, no matter which elements from $A$ and $B$ we choose. Note that such a $c$ might not be rational.

Comment: You need in fact $a<b$ to apply Archimedes property (doesn't work when $a=b$).

Comment: @Arthur and @ coffeemath thank you  i understood ..

Comment: Let $c=((\sup A )+(\inf B))/2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $c=\sup A$. Then $c \in \mathbb R$, since any element of $B$ is an upper bound of $A$.

Now $a\leq c$ for all $a\in A$ by definition of $c$. Also, $c \leq b$ for all $b\in B$, because if $b<c$ for some $b \in B$, we have $c-b>0$ and by the definition of $c$ we can find $a \in A$ s.t

$$ a + (c-b) > c$$

so

$$a>b$$

Which is a contradiction with the assumption.

Comment: .......thank you so much

Comment: @surest You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Take $ c= sup\{a : a \in A \} $